# jQuery/Javascript: Waiting for an animation to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me preface this by saying I am new to Javascript, but not to programming. I call `fadeOut` on a jQuery Object like such:

```
$(x).fadeOut('fast');
```

I have other things that will be fading out and in, but I need them to wait for each other, and I do not necessarily know how many are going to be doing this. `x` is a string from an array that contains the items that are are fading in or out. In my first attempt I used the callback function in `fadeOut` like this:

```
$(x).fadeOut('fast', function(){ foo(modifiedArray); })
```

Where `foo` is the method I want, and modifiedArray is the array minus `x`. This still didn't make it wait though, so next I tried:

```
$(x).fadeOut('fast');
while( $(x).css('display') != 'none' ){}
foo(modifiedArray);
```

But the loop never ends. How can I make the animation wait before I call `foo(modifiedArray)` again?

EDIT: Here is the full code

```
function animateElements(elements){
if (elements.length == 1){
    var x = elements[0];
    $(x).fadeIn('slow');
}
else{
    var x = elements.pop();
    $(x).fadeOut('fast');
    while(  $(x).css('display') != 'none' ){}
    animateElements(elements);
}
}
```

Comment: Why didn't the callback work? What happened?

Comment: What do you mean by you want them to wait for each other? Do you mean you want to run them in sequence, so element1 fades in, then element2 fades in, etc?

Comment: Your first try(call back) should work well, investigate on another things that may cause this not to work

Comment: @SLaks All of the elements fade in and out out of sequence

Comment: perhaps the `modifiedArray` was modified again before the handler got to it? Any chance you called the `fadeOut` with callback from within a loop?

Comment: This question is pretty easy but the lack of context of your provided code is making more complicated than it really is. No kidding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness. In your code you can fix the following things.

1. Use `.fadeIn()` instead of `.fadeOut()`.

   ```
   $(x).fadeIn('slow');
     ---^---
   ```
2. You may want to use `.shift()` instead of `.pop()` to go over the array from left to right, not from right to left.

   ```
   var x = elements.pop();
                 ---^---
   ```
3. Call the recursive step in the complete callback of `.fadeOut()` avoiding to check compulsively the element's style.

   ```
   $(x).fadeOut('fast');
     ---^---
   while(  $(x).css('display') != 'none' ){}
   animateElements(elements);
   ```
4. Use `elements.length == 0` as a base case. This will improve readability.

   ```
   if (elements.length == 1) {
     --^--
   ```

At the end, the code will look like this:

```
function animateElements(elements) {
  if (elements.length) {
    var x = elements.shift();
    $(x).fadeOut('fast', function(){
      animateElements(elements);
    });
  }
}
```

[See it live](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ8fP/).

Answer (score 3):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3cn3z/3/

```
function sequentialFade(items, duration) {
    var arr = 'shift' in items ? items : items.get();
    var item = arr.shift();

    $(item).fadeOut(duration, function(){
        sequentialFade(arr, duration);
    });
}

sequentialFade($("div"), "slow");
```

Let me know if you feel this needs explaining.

This can also written as a small jQuery plugin like so: http://jsfiddle.net/3cn3z/1/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.seqFade = function(duration) {
        var items = this.get();

        (function fadeStep(){
            var item = items.shift();
            $(item).fadeOut(duration, fadeStep);
        })();

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And used like:

```
$("div").seqFade("slow");
```

To take it a step further, we can generalize the plugin to use any built-in jQuery animation function: http://jsfiddle.net/3cn3z/5/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.seqAnim = function(animFunc, duration, callback) {
        var items = this.get();
        var me = this;
        (function animStep(){
            var item = items.shift();

            if (item == undefined && callback != undefined)
                callback.call(me)
            else
                $(item)[animFunc](duration, animStep);
        })();

        return me;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Used like:

```
$("div").delay(500).seqAnim("slideToggle", "slow", function(){
    this.delay(500).seqAnim("fadeIn", 500);
});
```

​

Comment: `sequentialFade` accept two arguments but only one will get passed from the callback, meaning the `duration` will be undefined the second time around.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks, didn't notice.

Comment: The demo still exhibits the incorrect behavior. Should be updated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected your code to :

```
    function animateElements(elements) {
        if (elements.length == 1) {
            var x = elements[0];
            $(x).fadeOut('slow');  // Should this be fade out?
        }
        else {
            var x = elements.pop();
            $(x).fadeOut('slow', function () { animateElements(elements) });
        }
    }
```

There are three issues with your code.  Firstly, you are using a loop rather than the callback function.  Second, the callback function needs to be a function - even if it's anonymous.  Thirdly, you have `FadeIn()` instead of `fadeOut()` when `length == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function animateElements(elements) {
    if (elements.length == 1) {
        var x = elements[0];
        $(x).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        var x = elements.pop();
        $(x).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            animateElements(elements);
        });
    }
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PGea3/1/)